# I would like for a previous setTimeout() call to be cancelled upon mouseenter but I can not understand why jQuery wont let me do it?

Tags: jquery, css, queue

This is my code:

```
$(".pc2").hover(function(){

        $('#pc1').show();
        $('#pc1a').show(800);
    },
    function(){
        $('#pc1').hide();
        setTimeout(function(){$('#pc1a').hide();}, 5000);
        $('#pc1a').mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(function(){$('#pc1a').show();}); 
        });
        $('#pc1a').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#pc1a').hide(800);
        });
    });
```

What I would like is that the $('pc1a') div stays ( so that the setTimeout( hide()) does not get called ) once the user floats his mouse enters the div. This seems like it would have an easy solution using stop(); , clearTimeout(); or clearQueue(); but I'm unsure how to call these methods properly based on my situation. Could you please advise me and help me find a solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clearTimeout` accepts a previous timer handle, not a function. Save the return value of `setTimeout`, and then use that value later to cancel it.

For example:

```
$(".pc2").hover(
    function () {
        $('#pc1').show();
        $('#pc1a').show(800);
    },
    function () {
        var timer;

        $('#pc1').hide();
        timer = setTimeout(function () {     // <== Save it
            $('#pc1a').hide();
        }, 5000);
        $('#pc1a').mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);             // <== Cancel it
        });
        $('#pc1a').mouseleave(function () {
            $('#pc1a').hide(800);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will approve answer once Stack lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `clearTimeout` by id, Try this (*Updated)

```
$(".pc2").hover(function() {
        $('#pc1').show();
        $('#pc1a').show(800);
    },
    function() {
        var timeoutId;
        $('#pc1').hide();
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){$('#pc1a').hide();}, 5000);
        $('#pc1a').mouseenter(function(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutId); 
        });
        $('#pc1a').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#pc1a').hide(800);
        });
    }
);
```